# How prove $p$ have contains infinite prime numbers

Tags: number-theory

give the  natural Numbers $a,b,c$,and such $a<b<c$, if exsit prime number $p$, such

> $$p+a,p+b,p+c$$ are Composite numbers,

**show that:such this contidtion  $p$ have contains infinite prime numbers**.

My idea: for example $a=2,b=3,c=4$.

> (1)then we take $p=23$ is prime number.and
>   the
>   $$p+a=25,p+b=26,p+c=27$$ are composite numbers
>
> (2)and an other prime number $p=31$, 
>   then 
>   $$p+a=33,p+b=34,p+c=35$$ are composite numbers too.
>
> (3) and take $p=47$,is prime number.and
>   $$p+a=49,p+b=50,p+c=51$$ are composite numbers too

**and so on $\cdots$**

For other any example,such
$$a=3,b=5,c=7$$

(1)then we take $p=3$,then
$$p+a=6,p+b=8,p+c=10$$ are composite numbers

(2) take $p=5$, then
$$p+a=8,p+b=10,p+c=12$$ are composite numbers

**and so on $\cdots$**

Now How prove my question,I think this is interesting problem,But I don't prove it,Thank you

Comment: I just can't understand what the question is... the english doesn't help, either.

Comment: mean this:give $a,b,c\in N^{+}$,then we can find  infinite prime numbers $p$,such $p+a,p+b,p+c$ are composide numbers.

Comment: This follows immediately from Dirichlet's Theorem on Primes in Arithmetic Progression, doesn't it?

Comment: @WillO,Yes,That's my mean.Thank you

Comment: @GerryMyerson,Hello,This problem is from china Mathematical olympiad Problem Mo 1,see there http://tieba.baidu.com/p/2633544674

Comment: I wasn't asking you where it came from, I was telling you how to solve it. But the answer by AN is better.

Comment: @GerryMyerson,sorry I understand your meaning. Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Recall that there are arbitrarily long gaps between consecutive primes. So for example let $N\gt c$. Then there are  $N-1$ consecutive composites between $N!+2$ and $N!+N$. Let $p$ be the largest prime $\le N!+1$.

We  can "start" this construction after any prime $q$, thereby getting infinitely many $p$ with the required property.

Comment: That beats my idea.